# Find the sum of the greatest odd divisor of all integers 1 through N

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am  given a positive integer N. f(N) is the greatest odd divisor of N.

Find the sum (f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+....f(N))%m.

What should be the faster algorithm for this in case N is of order 10^18  and m can be up to 10^9?

Example brute force algorithm:

```
int sum=0;
int a[n+1];
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    if(i%2!=0)
        a[i] = i;
    else
        a[i] = a[i/2];
}
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    sum+=a[i];
}
cout<<sum;
```

Comment: This is not C++ question.

Comment: In coding,which approach can use?

Comment: What is f(3)? Is it 3?

Comment: @sukesh You can select any language. It can be C, C++, Python, Java, etc. The algorithm doesn't depend on a specific language.

Comment: I am using brute force approach

Comment: Does "odd divisor" include N itself if N is odd?

Comment: yes,it can include

Comment: As said above, the greatest odd divisor of an odd number is itself, so you can extract those and find a closed form solution to that half of the problem. For the even numbers, the greatest odd divisor is the product of all the odd prime divisors, so divide by 2 until the result is odd.

Comment: I am doing same . But it is showing error in code output

Comment: Note that if you run brute force, not only will the program be brutally slow, but it will also overflow the capacity of the integer types commonly available today.

Comment: can u please edit my code

Comment: Consider the odd number `m`, which can be represented by `M` bits, and has a 1 as the LSB. The number is written as `a_M a_(M-1) ... a_1 1`. `m` is the greatest odd divisor for itself, and all numbers of the form `a_M a_(M-1) ... a_1 1 [0 0 0 ... 0]` which is the same bit pattern but with more zeros. So you can have a primary loop on all odd numbers, and an inner loop that increases this until the number is greater than the max. Add and modulo.

Comment: Your current approach would show that the greatest odd divisor of 4 is 2.

Answer (score 6):

The sum of the odd integers in the range [1,N] is the square of the number of odd integers, or ((N+1)/2)^2, where '/' represents integer division. Let's call this p(N).

We still need to find sum of the largest odd divisor of the even integers in the range [1,N]. We can split the even integers in the range by the max power of 2 that divides them.

```
For 1 power of 2: p(N/2)
For 2 powers of 2: p(N/4)
For 3 powers of 2: p(N/8)
```

etc...

I.e., f(N) = p(N) + p(N/2) + p(N/4) + p(N/8) + ...

Here are the results for N = 1, 2, ..., 20:

```
N,  f(N)
1,    1
2,    2
3,    5
4,    6
5,   11
6,   14
7,   21
8,   22
9,   31
10,  36
11,  47
12,  50
13,  63
14,  70
15,  85
16,  86
17, 103
18, 112
19, 131
20, 136
```

Comment: Gorgeous! I kept getting closer and closer to this last night since the question intrigued me, but didn't quite get there. This did it. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly taking Dave's solution, but adding code.

Find:

```
F(N) mod M = (f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(N)) mod M
```

Given:

```
1.  f(n) = greatest odd divisor of n
1a. f(n) = n, for all odd n
1b. f(n) = f(n/2), for all even n
    (note, this is recursive: f(n) = f(n/2) = f(n/4) = ... until we hit an odd number)
2.  p(n) = sum of all odd numbers less than or equal to n
2a. p(n) = (number of odd numbers less than or equal to n) squared
3.  F(N) = f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(N)
4.  1 <= N <= 10^18
5.  1 <= M <= 10^9
```

Then:

```
F(N) = p(N) + [f(2) + f(4) + ... + f(largest even not > N)]
     = p(N) + [f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(N/2)]
     = p(N) + F(N/2)
     = p(N) + p(N/2) + p(N/4) + ...

and 

F(N) mod M = (p(N) mod M + p(N/2) mod M + ...) mod M
```

`p(N)` has complexity `O(1)` and the recursive `F(N)` has complexity `O(log N)` which will be significantly faster than the brute force approaches which could be `O(N log N)` (I believe. Someone verify this).

The following C++ code accomplishes this algorithm

```
#include <iostream>

using value_type = unsigned long long;

value_type p_N_mod_M(value_type N, value_type M)
{
    // nom := _N_umber of _O_dd numbers not greater than N, _M_od-M
    value_type nom = ((N + 1) / 2) % M;
    return (nom * nom) % M;
}

value_type F_N_mod_M(value_type N, value_type M)
{
    if (N == 0) return 0;
    if (N == 1) return 1;

    return (p_N_mod_M(N, M) + F_N_mod_M(N / 2, M)) % M;
}

int main()
{
    value_type N, M;
    std::cout << "Calculates F(N) mod M = (f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(N)) mod M,\n"
        "where f(n) is the greatest odd divisor of n.\n"
        " [1 <= N <= 10^18]; [1 <= M <= 10^9]\n"
        "------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
        "Enter N followed by M: ";
    std::cin >> N >> M;

    std::cout << "\nF(" << N << ") mod " << M << " = " << F_N_mod_M(N, M) << "\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
Calculates F(N) mod M = (f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(N)) mod M,
where f(n) is the greatest odd divisor of n.
 [1 <= N <= 10^18]; [1 <= M <= 10^9]
------------------------------------------------------------------
Enter N followed by M: 20 200

F(20) mod 200 = 136

----

Calculates F(N) mod M = (f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(N)) mod M,
where f(n) is the greatest odd divisor of n.
 [1 <= N <= 10^18]; [1 <= M <= 10^9]
------------------------------------------------------------------
Enter N followed by M: 20 135

F(20) mod 135 = 1
```